# How to show adsense ads through HTML DOM element

Tags: javascript, php

I use below mentioned code to create HTML DOM div element 312 and i want to show adsense ad inside this div named 312 on other page by calling javascript to create dom element. It is working fine for other ads but not for adsense ads. Kindly help me.

```
        <script>
    document.getElementById('312').innerHTML = "<div style='box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; width:300px; height:250px; position:relative;border: 1px solid #666;' class='pc_block_active'><script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
    <!-- 300*250 box -->
    <ins class='adsbygoogle'
         style='display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px'
         data-ad-client='ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX'
         data-ad-slot='XXXXXXXXX'></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script></div>"
        </script>


<div id="312">WANT TO SHOW AD IN THIS DIV</div>
```

I use below given code to call dom element

```
<script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var randpubc = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1); var pubc = document.createElement('script'); pubc.type = 'text/javascript'; pubc.async = true; pubc.src = '//xyz.com/cdn/3312.js?r='+parseInt(randpubc); var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(pubc, s); })(); </script>
<div id="312"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Move the `ins` into desired `div`

```
<div id="312">
    <ins class='adsbygoogle'
         style='display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px'
         data-ad-client='ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX'
         data-ad-slot='XXXXXXXXX'></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: div 312 is placed on other website and call above said javascript from other website having adsense code. ie javascript code and div are on different servers.

Comment: @John, can you post how you call the other resource? There must be an iframe here.